# Sencha Touch packaged app & social auth

Tags: cordova, oauth, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm developing a Sencha Touch 2 mobile app that is to be packaged for app-stores distribution.
I need to implement social auth (facebook, twitter, OpenId). I will be packaging my app with cordova/phonegap. How does authentication workflow differ in such an app from the web app?
Is there any link, or can anyone explain the workflow in this case?

As I read, auth workflows (mostly facebook is mentioned) that work in browser with regular hosted web-app, dont seem to work so well when you package the app with phonegap.
This may be due to redirect/callback urls used with oauth.

Any advice on the difference in workflow / links to this already beeing implemented?

EDIT: I will be using django on the backend. I am in a bit of a dilemma as to how useful django-allauth or django-social-auth plugins will be in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Facebook you can use the Facebook Connect PhoneGap plugin. The implementation is almost the same as the web based versions, but if it is packaged with PhoneGap the Javascript SDK will hook into the native Facebook app for authentication.

For the others you can take a look at this OAuth plugin: https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap I've never used this one though.

Comment: Josh, I will need to try it out, and see how far that plugin takes me :)

Comment: By the way, can I use facebook plugin with Phonegap Build? What would be the workflow?

Comment: Yes you can use it with PhoneGap Build. Check out the docs here https://build.phonegap.com/plugins you just have to reference your Facebook App Id and App Name in the config.xml file and make some references in your index.html

Comment: I made the thing work.. Can you tell me, this oauth plugin.. Can I 
use it with Build? Or adapt or include it somehow to make it work with Build?
I'm thinking an in-app browser may be a nicer solution, but I haven't used it yet.

Comment: Basically, oauth plugin you mentioned, hooks up to a commercial service provider.